# Probability of getting exactly 2 Heads separated by at least 1 Tail for n tosses

Tags: probability

Consider n ≥ 3 independent tosses of a coin with P(H) = p, 0 ≤ p ≤ 1. Find the
probability that only two heads are observed (but no more and no fewer) and that these two heads are separated by at least one tail.

The thing about being separated by at least one tail is tripping me up. I don't know how to set up the problem. I'm thinking that it has something to do with the equation $$\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ I don't know if I'm even using the correct equation here. Anyone have an idea of how to do this problem? Thanks

Comment: Is overlap counted? For example, $HTHTH$ would be counted as one or two?

Comment: No, only 2 heads allowed

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:Try thinking like this ..The probability is :

**P**(*exactly 2 heads*)**-P**( *exactly two heads with the two heads being consecutive*)

---

We now use Bernoulli's trials (you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)
.

Now the probability of exactly two heads=$\binom{n}{2}p^2{(1-p)}^{n-2}$

also we can take two consecutive positions in $n-1$ ways.

thus: P( *exactly two heads with the two heads being consecutive*)=$(n-1)p^2{(1-p)}^{n-2}$

Can you end it now?

Comment: thanks, your hint was really helpful

Comment: @GrandNecro you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The probability of having exactly two heads in some particular order is $p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$. There are in total ${n \choose 2}$ possible orders without any restriction. Out of which, there are $n-1$ orders where they are one after the other, so you need to subtract them and get
$$\left({n \choose 2}-(n-1)\right)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$$